# My table view cells collapse when I open it first time and after once working fine iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

when I run my application  first time,  I got below image and after rotating in landscape and again  portrait it works fine .

Can Anyone tell / suggest me, What is the issue ?

[image]

---

---

---

**This is the actual view what I need. The fields BUST, HIPS, Waist labels are generated by programatically not through the storyboard**

[image]

Comment: check / cut your constraints, the issue must comes from that

Comment: Wait... I 'll check @James03

Comment: I add all missing constraints but still it is not working @James03

Comment: Plase share some code about your implementation. We cannot do anything  with this information, only guesses.